# How do i find the equation of a parabola given the max and two points

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

The points of the parabola are (10,0) and (42,0). The maximum is 22. If you could show me the equation and how to find it, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has the form $y=a(x-h)^2+k$, you just need to know the vertex $(h,k)$ and the scaling constant $a$.

Hint: The max here is the $y$ coordinate of the vertex, and the $x$ coordinate of the vertex lies halfway between the two $x$-intercepts.

Use one of the points you know the parabola passes thru to find $a$.

Comment: Thank you John, you really helped me out